# Does Oracle 19c support Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, oracle-19c

I am trying to install Oracle 19c, and It needs X-display so I typed xhost +, but it doesn't work. Any ideas to solve this problem? Also, I want to know that Ubuntu literally support Oracle 19c.

Comment: Yes it supports

Comment: "it doesn't work" Can you elaborate? What happens when you type it? Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle does *NOT* support Ubuntu. From the documentation:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/ladbi/operating-system-checklist-for-oracle-database-installation-on-linux.html#GUID-E5C0A90E-7750-45D9-A8BC-C7319ED934F0

The following Linux x86-64 kernels are supported:

- Oracle Linux 8.1 with the Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel 6:
  5.4.17-2011.0.7.el8uek.x86_64 or later Oracle Linux 8 with the Red Hat Compatible kernel: 4.18.0-80.el8.x86_64 or later
- Oracle Linux 7.4 with the Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel 4:
  4.1.12-124.19.2.el7uek.x86_64 or later Oracle Linux 7.4 with the Unbreakable
  Enterprise Kernel 5: 4.14.35-1818.1.6.el7uek.x86_64 or
  later Oracle Linux 7.7 with the Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel 6:
  5.4.17-2011.4.4.el7uek.x86_64 or later Oracle Linux 7.5 with the Red Hat Compatible Kernel: 3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64 or later
- Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8: 4.18.0-80.el8.x86_64 or later
- Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.5: 3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64 or later
- SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15: 4.12.14-23-default or later
- SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP3: 4.4.162-94.72-default or later

Ubuntu is an entirely different branch of Linux, and no matter how many people claim they have hacked it to work, it is NOT supported and results are NOT guaranteed.

Comment: There are docker images now, though. https://container-registry.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=113:10::::::

Comment: From the registry description: "The Oracle Database server docker image contains Oracle
Database server Release 19c (19.3.0.0) Enterprise or Standard Edition
running on Oracle Linux 7." Still not Ubuntu.

Comment: The Oracle Linux 7 bits are inside the container image.

Comment: The OP didn't ask about Docker, he asked if Oracle was supported on Ubuntu, which it is not.

Comment: Fair enough, and it may not be officially _supported_.  But I suspect the question was really "Can I run Oracle on my Ubuntu box?" In which case docker is a simple solution.  Easier by far than actually installing Oracle on Linux.

Comment: Also, Oracle needs the RHEL kernel, which is not part of the container by definition (a Docker image is not a full VM), so running this image on Ubuntu wouldn't be supported either.

Comment: In order for it to work, you must be running on a supported kernel: RHEL, OL, or SuSE.

Comment: It works, it's just not supported for a production deployment.  I'm running it on Docker on Windows Subsystem For Linux, which is certainly not a supported configuration either.